# flanneld not functioning with base kubernetes install | centos | virtualbox

Tags: linux, centos, kubernetes, flannel

Thanks for the read.

I'd like to preface this with the fact that I am weak on dev-ops! :)

First off, my environment:
3 node cluster each of which are CentOS 7 VMs running in VirtualBox 5.1.3.  I have an additional network adaptor enabled running an internal network visible only to the VMs.

I have configured the VMs to use the additional adaptor and am able to ping all nodes via it's network.

etcd config:

```
{ "Network": "172.30.0.0/24", "Backend": { "Type": "vxlan" } }
```

nmcli output:

```
enp0s3: connected to enp0s3
    "Intel 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter)"
    ethernet (e1000), 08:00:27:DD:CB:CA, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 10.0.2.15/24
    inet6 fe80::49e4:5aa5:65c8:6e48/64

enp0s8: connected to enp0s8
    "Intel 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter)"
    ethernet (e1000), 08:00:27:40:11:AE, hw, mtu 1500
    inet4 192.168.0.10/24
    inet6 fe80::90cc:f3b4:7e73:cf3f/64
```

I am working through the installation/configuration instructions in the following [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/).

I wanted to run through this full installation to grasp the overall topology if the product.

Installation seems to be fine and I am able to deploy pods to the cluster.  The issue is that flanneld does not seem to be working. I have it explicitly bound to the internal network adapter in the config (enp0s8), however it's showing:

```
flannel.1: disconnected
    "flannel.1"
    vxlan, 0A:91:01:BC:7D:7D, sw, mtu 1450
```

Any insight on this issue would be appreciated.  I have done due diligence before reaching out to the community!

Thanks in advance.

Braden

Comment: Have you seen [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/604)? it also links to a [vxlan straight-face test](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/networking/vxlan.html#check-the-capability-of-your-system) which you may find helpful

Comment: Thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I'll take a look at the document.  I simply assumes support, which was probably a fail on my part.

Comment: I check the document:

uname -r
3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64

Saw this oddness in the logs:

Jan  5 13:33:50 node-master NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1515177230.6950] device (flannel.1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jan  5 13:33:50 node-master NetworkManager[662]: <info>  [1515177230.6973] device (flannel.1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]

(the code format is not working for some reason)